# OAuth 2.0 for shortener API

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

I'am trying to generate unique URLs, and then check this in https://goo.gl/. My code in python:

```
import requests
import json



def goo_shorten_url(url):
    post_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    payload = {'longUrl': url}
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print r.text



    goo_shorten_url('http://www.google.com')
```

However I can't understand how to modifies my code and configure a token in order to get this unique URLs

Comment: It looks like you are supplying an API key in the URL. If that is the case, then you don't need to supply an OAuth token.

Comment: I see. So why when I perform goo_shorten_url('google.com') I get the same url ? This happening because I don't have a token to get personal information. This KEY on my URL I guess is just in order to use the api, but not to use with personal values. "An auth token is optional for shorten requests. If you provide one, the short URL will be unique, and it will show up in the authenticated user's dashboard at goo.gl." (developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started) What I did wrong?